# Get multiple elements by a list of id's with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have that in my html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1234">
<input type="checkbox" id="2345">
<input type="checkbox" id="3456">
<input type="checkbox" id="4567">
<input type="checkbox" id="5678">
```

And an list of id `1234 2345 3456` or `#1234 #2345 #3456`

I want to get all the element of the list whose id is in the list of id

I try `$(":checkbox").attr('id', items_id);` and `var items_cb = $(":checkbox[id='items_id']");` where items_id is the list of item, but it doesn't work.

Comment: CSS IDs cannot begin with a number, you should change them to start with a letter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just try to put all id's in selector separated by comma:

```
$('#1234, #2345, #3456')...
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/3df6W/

P.S. ID's shouldn't start with digits.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('#1234, #2345, #3456')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `each` method that will loop through all the selected elements.

HTML

```
<input name="myradio" type="checkbox" id="colour1">
<input name="myradio "type="checkbox" id="colour2">
<input name="myradio" type="checkbox" id="colour3">
```

JavaScript

```
$('input:radio[name=myradio]').each(function (index) {
        alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val()); //is it checked?
        alert(index + ': ' + $(this).attr('id')); //ID string
        //You can compare if is this ID in items_id in this loop
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just build a selector string like :

```
var selectorString = '';
for id in idList:
    selectorString = '#' + idList[id] + ',';
```

then you can use the selectorString as :

```
 $(selectorString)
```

to select them.

Comment: i believe `id` should be `i`.

Comment: nah , the i should be id :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ['1234', '2345', '3456'];
var elem = [];
$('body > input').filter(function() {
    if ($.inArray(this.id, arr) != -1) {
        elem.push({
            id: this.id,
            type: $(this).prop('type'),
            name: this.nodeName
        });
    }
});
console.log(elem);
console.log(elem.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i < items_id.length; i++){  
    var id = items_id[i];
    result.push($(id))  
}
// result is what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#1234, #2345, #3456")
```

...should work.

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/